# Retrofit using Post

Tags: android

Everyone I need a testing web service where I can use my Retrofit post command to post, delete patch my data.I am getting error "unable to invoke no args constructor for interface retrofit2.http.POST.Registering an Instance Creator with G son for this type may fix this problem.

I am Thinking that may be my link to upload data is not working

```
//My post command in mainActivity.java

 private void getpost(){
        Post post = new Post(23,"Hello","new text");
        Call<POST> call = jsonPlaceHolder.createpost(post);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<POST>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<POST> call, Response<POST> response) {

                if (!response.isSuccessful()){
                    textView.setText("code: " + response.code());
                    return;
                }
                Post postresponse = (Post) response.body();

                String content = " ";
                content += "Code: " + response.code() + "\n";
                content += "Id:  " + postresponse.getId() + "\n\n";
                content += "User ID :" + postresponse.getUserid() + "\n\n";
                content += "Title :  " + postresponse.getTitle() + "\n\n";
                content += "Text :  " + postresponse.getBody() + "\n\n";
                textView.append(content);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<POST> call, Throwable t) {

                textView.setText(t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
```

`Api` coding

```
package com.example.learnretrofit;

import java.util.List;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.Body;
import retrofit2.http.GET;
import retrofit2.http.POST;

public interface Jsonapi {
  @POST("posts")
    Call<POST> createpost(@Body Post post);

}
```

Comment: What is `POST` and what is `Post`. Please name your classes differently because this is quite confusing both me and probably the JVM too

Comment: Post is just a different class name post and POST is the method used to call POST

Comment: Post and POST are horrible class names. Please use class names that make sense. https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

Comment: okie i am updating my code with  name "poster" instead of "Post" soo that iit will be easy and uh will also help me out

Comment: Post is just a class name  and POST is no class bt its just a method we call in API using  @POST

Answer (score 0):

You are passing Post when creating a retrofit call but in your interface, you expect the object of Poster.
Also, if you want some public API, 
https://dog.ceo/dog-api/, you can use this

Comment: updated pls check bt getting same error even when i am expecting the code of Post

Answer (score 0):

Here is one service you can use for free.

http://dummy.restapiexample.com/

and to your error you have just used **POST** from retrofit class instead of your **Post** model while creating **Call<>** object, so naming convention matters.

```
private void getpost(){
    Post post = new Post(23,"Hello","new text");
    Call<Post> call = jsonPlaceHolder.createpost(post);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Post>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Post> call, Response<Post> response) {

            if (!response.isSuccessful()){
                textView.setText("code: " + response.code());
                return;
            }
            Post postresponse = (Post) response.body();

            String content = " ";
            content += "Code: " + response.code() + "\n";
            content += "Id:  " + postresponse.getId() + "\n\n";
            content += "User ID :" + postresponse.getUserid() + "\n\n";
            content += "Title :  " + postresponse.getTitle() + "\n\n";
            Content += "Text:  " + post response. getBody () + "\n\n";
            textView.append(content);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Post> call, Throwable t) {

            textView.setText(t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

edit: you need to change here also.

```
public interface Jsonapi {
  @POST("posts")
    Call<Post> createpost(@Body Post post);

}
```

Actually, there are two models involved one in sending body request and one in receiving a response. So change accordingly in your case both Models are same i.e Post. If your response and request is same then this will work otherwise will throw error again. Create another Model for receiving the response based on json structure.

Comment: Not working sir its giving error as Change variable 'call' type to 'retrofit2.call<retrofit2.http.POST>'

Comment: when i chnge POST to Post

Comment: have added more clarification if you need more info do comment. @DaRkwArRiOr

Comment: Thank you sir for your concern but that problem was solved thank you can uh help my friend out?

Comment: " https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58913282/custom-recyclerview-using-adapter "